# Performing a SELECT Count on multiple tables with specific criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, count

I have four tables in a database being used to check for data accuracy. `[Participants]` has *ParticipantID* and 3 other tables `[PreForm]`, `[PostForm]`, `[ServiceForm]` are supposed to have the same amount of *ParticipantID*s as `[Participants]`.

The end goal of the query is to send a report to each community about their monthly counts. If they are inaccurate to a certain degree, we contact them. We are achieving this by doing a count on IDs across the tables.

My attempted query:

```
SELECT Participants.[community], COUNT(Participants.[ParticipantID]) AS 
Part_Count, 
COUNT(PreForm.[ParticipantID]) AS Pre_Count, 
COUNT(PostForm.[ParticipantID]) AS Post_Count, 
COUNT(ServiceForm.[ParticipantID]) AS Service_Count
FROM ((Participants INNER JOIN PreForm ON Participants.[ParticipantID] = PreForm.[ParticipantID]) 
INNER JOIN PostForm ON Participants.[ParticipantID] = PostForm.[ParticipantID]) 
INNER JOIN [ServiceForm] ON Participants.[ParticipantID] = [ServiceForm].ParticipantID
WHERE (((Participants.[Date]) Between #10/1/2019# And #11/30/2019#))
GROUP BY Participants.[community];
```

This query... kind of works? The counts are inaccurate. Even with LEFT Joins I get strange counts. I am aware that a LOT of issues could be resolved if these tables were normalized, but those aren't the cards I was dealt.

Can anyone identify what is going on in this query that is resulting in inaccurate counts? Is there a better way to do this?

edit: Here is a rough create/insert list:
CREATE TABLE Participants (ParticipantID TEXT PRIMARY KEY, Community TEXT); INSERT INTO Participants ("QWE", "US"); INSERT INTO Participants ("ASD", "US"); INSERT INTO Participants ("ZXC", "Mexico"); CREATE TABLE PreForm (ParticipantID TEXT); INSERT INTO PreForm ("QWE"); INSERT INTO PreForm ("ZXC"); CREATE TABLE ServiceForm (ParticipantID TEXT); INSERT INTO ServiceForm ("QWE");

```
{Participants}
[ID]           [Community]
QWE          US
ASD          US
ZXC          Mexico
{PreForm}
[ID]
QWE
ZXC
{ServiceForm}
[ID]
QWE
{Desired Query}
[Community]    [Part_Count]    [Pre_Count]    [Service_Count]
US             2                1              1
Mexico         1                1
```

Comment: Please share sample datasets(create and insert queries ) for further eval

Comment: CREATE TABLE Participants (ParticipantID TEXT PRIMARY KEY, Community TEXT); INSERT INTO Participants ("QWE", "US"); INSERT INTO Participants ("ASD", "US"); INSERT INTO Participants ("ZXC", "Mexico"); CREATE TABLE PreForm (ParticipantID TEXT); INSERT INTO PreForm ("QWE"); INSERT INTO PreForm ("ZXC"); CREATE TABLE ServiceForm (ParticipantID TEXT); INSERT INTO ServiceForm ("QWE");

Comment: sample insert queries ?

Comment: also please provide current and expected result screenshot if possible

Comment: Impossible since you use `Date` field in query! Please post actual sample data (redact as necessary).

Comment: If easier - ignore the date field. I can fiddle with that later. I am primarily having issues just getting the count straight.

Comment: So what does your current query return? With `LEFT JOIN`, it should return proper counts. But if `ParticipantID` can appear more than once than counts will double, triple, etc. The date or other indicator is important to capture uniqueness across tables. Please post a fuller sample.

Comment: With left join it returns a value of 90 for a community.. but if I just filter the table to that community it has 72 records with no nulls to account for the missing 18. If you say it is correct I will try looking for another explanation. I would screenshot my query and sample data to give you a better idea but it contains private information I cannot share.

Answer (score 0):

Likely, the counts are incorrect due to the granularity of the tables, specifically the uniqueness of `ParticipantID`. If the same `ParticipantID` can appear more than once in any table, then your `INNER JOIN` captures one-to-many or many-to-many pairings which will double, triple, quadruple, or other multiples of actual counts per each instance of `ParticipantID` (e.g., `18*4=72`, `18*5=90`).  And you may want to use `LEFT JOIN` if potentially `ParticipantIDs` can optionally appear in other tables.

To illustrate see these two fiddles (click <kbd>|> Run</kbd> for results) using your posted data and SQLite (the open-source file-level database counterpart of MS Access):

[Correct Counts Query with `LEFT JOIN`](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jJe1NyV4zLnnGDbqtkyKaw/0)  *(using exact posted data)*

```
| Community | Part_Count | Pre_Count | Service_Count |
| --------- | ---------- | --------- | ------------- |
| Mexico    | 1          | 1         | 0             |
| US        | 2          | 1         | 1             |
```

[Incorrect Counts Query with `LEFT JOIN`](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jJe1NyV4zLnnGDbqtkyKaw/1) *(same data but repeating `QWE` and `ZXC` in `PreForm`)*

```
| Community | Part_Count | Pre_Count | Service_Count |
| --------- | ---------- | --------- | ------------- |
| Mexico    | 2          | 2         | 0             |
| US        | 3          | 2         | 2             |
```

---

One solution is to add another field to the join clause that better capture uniqueness such as dates if no `ParticipantID` can appear more than once on a specific date and of course if date is available in all tables.

```
SELECT p.[community], 
       COUNT(p.[ParticipantID]) AS Part_Count, 
       COUNT(pre.[ParticipantID]) AS Pre_Count, 
       COUNT(post.[ParticipantID]) AS Post_Count, 
       COUNT(s.[ParticipantID]) AS Service_Count
FROM ((Participants p
LEFT JOIN PreForm pre 
       ON p.[ParticipantID] = pre.[ParticipantID]
      AND p.[Date] = pre.[Date]) 
LEFT JOIN PostForm post 
       ON p.[ParticipantID] = post.[ParticipantID]
      AND p.[Date] = post.[Date]) 
LEFT JOIN [ServiceForm] s 
       ON p.[ParticipantID] = s.ParticipantID
      AND p.[Date] = s.[Date]
WHERE (((p.[Date]) Between #10/1/2019# And #11/30/2019#))
GROUP BY p.[community];
```

If dates cannot adequately capture distinct records, possibly add a form indicator like `FormId` in case `ParticipantID` can fill out multiple but different forms within a day (or use both form and date).

```
SELECT p.[community], 
       COUNT(p.[ParticipantID]) AS Part_Count, 
       COUNT(pre.[ParticipantID]) AS Pre_Count, 
       COUNT(post.[ParticipantID]) AS Post_Count, 
       COUNT(s.[ParticipantID]) AS Service_Count
FROM ((Participants p
LEFT JOIN PreForm pre 
       ON p.[ParticipantID] = pre.[ParticipantID]
      AND p.[FormID] = pre.[FormID]) 
LEFT JOIN PostForm post 
       ON p.[ParticipantID] = post.[ParticipantID]
      AND p.[FormID] = post.[FormID]) 
LEFT JOIN [ServiceForm] s 
       ON p.[ParticipantID] = s.ParticipantID
      AND p.[FormID] = s.[FormID]
WHERE (((p.[Date]) Between #10/1/2019# And #11/30/2019#))
GROUP BY p.[community];
```

NOTE: if you add other join fields, then you are counting `ParticipantID` and `Date` or `ParticipantID` and `FormId` (not `ParticipantID` alone) per `Commnity`.

Finally, if there is no other available field as your small mock data shows, then this is a database design issue and not SQL query one. You will have to redesign the tables accordingly by adding a date, form, or some other indicator in the tables to better capture uniqueness for comparison purposes.

Comment: Thank you, this is an excellent answer. Unfortunately, forms can be filled out days or weeks apart. The only identifier between them is the ParticipantID (Trust me, this database is killing me as much as it is you). I'll use some of your information to get to as close of a solution as I can. I've found other answers dealing with SELECT DISTINCT on multiple fields and will try that route as well. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Once again, this may be a database design and not coding issue. You do not describe your workflow or application(s) that uses this database. A table of one column does not seem too useful. I am sure you can find another indicator (possibly concatenation of other columns).